# Кнопка "Купить в один клик"

Tags: drupal

Как добавить кнопку "Купить в один клик" в drupal commerce? Есть ли какие готовые модули?

Comment: Рабочий линк на модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_buy_one_click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть для этих целей модуль Commerce Buy One Click - я писал о нем
http://drup.by/articles/knopka-kupit-v-odin-klik-dlya-drupal-commerce

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться модулями colorboxnode и  webform

Answer (score 1):

можно  сделать с помощью Jquery ui dialog  входящего в ядро друпала